# Ubuntu install on external USB hard drive with ntdlr missing error

Tags: installation, dual-boot, partitioning, usb, drive

I am relatively new to ubuntu and have a desktop with windows 7 installed on it. I would like to install ubuntu onto a samsung external hard drive which I have connected via USB 3.0. I have partitioned the 500 GB drive with 420 GB left in the NTFS format, a swap partition that is twice my RAM (which may be overkill), a FAT32 parition of 20 GB for a shared portion, and a 20 GB ext4 partition for the boot.

I have changed the BIOS setting to boot from my USB device first, but I keep getting an error that says "ntldr missing".

I appreciate any help anyone has on how to correct or fix the situation. I can explain more if there needs to be more detail.

Answer (score 0):

You need to boot Ubuntu, either from a live DVD or flash drive.

See: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-desktop-latest